# Unlocking account at startup immediately uses one attempt at passphrase

Tags: go-ethereum

Whenever I start the `geth` client:

```
geth --unlock
```

the console gets populated with a couple of messages `I0614 ....`
Then the phrase `Unlocking account 0 | Attempt 1/3` appears followed by more `I06014...` stuff, immediately on the same line like the passphrase request. It apparently considers tha startup messages as passphrase attemt, because then only comes the second try `Phassphrase  |  Attempt 2/3`, where I can actually start typing.

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

That happens because of the default verbosity level (3=info). Just set the verbosity level one or more steps down (2=warn should be enough) like this:

```
geth --unlock 0 --verbosity 2
```

and you will have all the time you need to type in your password.

If you want to change the verbosity level after you typed the password, attach to the node (or start it from the beginning with `console` parameter) and use

```
debug.verbosity(3)
```

to set default verbosity level again.